# How to join many tables with composite keys

Tags: sql

I have a base table with two columns primary key and two tables with two columns foreign key (one to many). Base table contains two rows, second and third per 4 row with equal keys. I tried to join all tables but got doubled result.
Could you help me to write select which will return only 4 rows?

```
select *
from base
         join joined_first jf on base.column_a = jf.column_a and base.column_b = jf.column_b
         join joined_second js on base.column_a = js.column_a and base.column_b = js.column_b;
```

expected

```
a1  b1  c1  a1  b1  d11 e11
a1  b1  c1  a1  b1  d12 e12
a1  b2  c1  a1  b2  d21 e21
a1  b2  c1  a1  b2  d22 e22


create table base
(
    column_a       varchar(20) not null,
    column_b       varchar(20) not null,
    column_c       varchar(20),
    primary key (column_a, column_b)
);

create table joined_first
(
    column_a           varchar(20) not null,
    column_b           varchar(20) not null,
    column_d           varchar(20),
    foreign key (column_a, column_b) references base (column_a, column_b)
);

create table joined_second
(
    column_a           varchar(20) not null,
    column_b           varchar(20) not null,
    column_e           varchar(20),
    foreign key (column_a, column_b) references base (column_a, column_b)
);

insert into base (column_a, column_b,column_c)
values  ('a1', 'b1', 'c1'),
        ('a1', 'b2', 'c1');

insert into joined_first (column_a, column_b, column_d)
values ('a1', 'b1', 'd11'),
       ('a1', 'b1', 'd12'),
       ('a1','b2','d21'),
       ('a1','b2','d22');

insert into joined_second (column_a, column_b, column_e)
values ('a1', 'b1', 'e11'),
       ('a1', 'b1', 'e12'),
       ('a1','b2','e21'),
       ('a1','b2','e22');
```

Comment: Tag your question with the database you are using.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want to "stack" the columns from the two tables.  To do this, you can generate a sequence number and use that for the `join`:

```
select *
from base b join
     (select jf.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column_a, column_b order by column_d) as seqnum
      from joined_first jf
     ) jf
     on b.column_a = jf.column_a and
        b.column_b = jf.column_b join
     (select js.*,
             row_number() over (partition by column_a, column_b order by column_e) as seqnum
      from joined_second js
     )js
     on b.column_a = js.column_a and
        b.column_b = js.column_b and
        jf.seqnum = js.seqnum;
```

[Here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2019&fiddle=f7cd02c6b2ef3c3e2fb12fc6183c0888) is a db<>fiddle.